# Failed to create project. clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory) not supported on JDK 9+. Eclipse Oxygen EE jdk 1.8.0 u301

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I try to create a Maven project with Eclipse Oxygen EE using JDK 1.8.0 u301 but when i click finish give this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPLsR.png).
I don't understand how to solve it because I'm not using JDK 9.
I checked if I had  more JDK installed but found nothing.

Comment: Use a more recent version of Eclipse because Oxygen is about 5 years old...(at least)... see https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: It's strange. Just in case, check the java version used by eclipse itsef in the eclipse.ini file. It should be java 8 or less AFAIU.  The reference to the java version is just below the "-vm" parameter. Mine, for example, is java 16 and appears in the following way:
plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149/jre/bin

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise i downloaded the last Eclipse EE version and works now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Pedro I try that solution but diden't work out so i suppose its something with Eclipse EE version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @khmarbaise I downloaded the last version of Eclipse EE:
[Eclipse JEE 2022-03-R-win32-x86_64](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2022-03/R/eclipse-jee-2022-03-R-win32-x86_64.zip)
I suppose it was something related to eclipse version and maven version.
I used the same JDK and JRE for both version.